# Multivariate regression in Tensorflow where dependent variables also depend on each other

Tags: r, regression, tensorflow, spss

Dear Stackoverflow community,

I would like to understand how to implement a multivariate regression in Tensorflow, where all the dependent variables y<sub>n</sub> depend on both input variables x<sub>n</sub> as well as the other dependent variables y<sub>n</sub>.

Let me explain the problem in a little more (simplified/generalized) detail:

- Let's assume Joe is a gamer who loves to play games in county fairs
- For every visit to a county fair, Joe would typically play multiple games (Shooting range, Lottery, fishing...)
- For each of these games, there are different types of prices. Let's simplify and say there are 3 types: toys, tickets (for visiting attractions), and cash. There is not a single type of price for each game, so for example if Joe spends $100 on a single game, he might get 5 toys, 2 tickets and $5 back in cash
- For every game, there is a distinct spent vs. gain curve for Joe. Those curves could represent diminishing gains when he spents more on the same game during one visit (since he becomes worn out, bored), or that he is better at some games vs. others. This might not be true from a pure maths point of view, but let's assume that in practice there are such curves
- There is data from Joe's past visits: spends for every game and overall gain (total number of toys, tickets and money) for every visit (not every game!)
- The big overarching question is: how should Joe optimize his spending for the next visit (i.e., how much should he be spending on each game), if he wants a certain amount of toys, tickets and cash?

The way I am trying to solve this problem at the moment consists of two major steps

1. Run a multivariate regression on all his past visits. This will yield Joe's typical gain vs. spend curves for all games
2. Maximize the gain for a given total budget by optimizing is spend on each game

Now this questions focuses on the 1. step of the approach. (Second step will come in a separate question since I feel this problem is too large to discuss in one question)

Would a FF Neural Network with multiple outputs be suitable for this problem? As someone without statistics or CS background, I do not fully understand the difference in ANN between training multiple NN with one single dependent variable and training one NN with multiple dependent variables.

In this case for example, I would like to understand the influence of how much Joe spends on each game on what he will get back. One game might be great for getting toys, another game would be most suitable for tickets (Remember we cannot run regressions on a game-by-game basis since we only know what Joe gets after every VISIT, not every GAME). Running separate single dependent regressions for toys, tickets, money would not fully work in my (limited) understanding since we cannot take the full spend-per-game for a regression on toys only, but have to distribute the spend-per-game on toys, tickets and cash with a proper weighting.

If a FF NN with multiple outputs cannot solve the problem, what would be other ways to do the regression?

Thanks a lot in advance for taking your time to read this, and sorry if this question is rather basic for someone without a long statistics/AI background.

Comment: Hi @Ruehri, I'm interested in a similar kind of problem, would you mind if I slightly modify the question to include examples in Theano plus a suggestion about the network setup? 

I would also start a 50 bounty :)

Comment: @TommasoGuerrini sure please do so. In the meanwhile I have tried running it in TensorFlow, seemed to work quite well.